# Wso2 ESB Integration With Tibco EMS 4.6 throws MessageFormatException. How to resolve?

Tags: wso2, jms, tibco, tibco-ems, wso2-esb

I have tried integrating WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 with Tibco EMS 4.6, added all the required jars of Tibco to WSO2 ESB repository/components/lib folder.

While sending the request to Tibco EMS as text/plain, got the below exception in the Tibco EMS end.

```
There was an error while parsing a message.
caused by: com.tibco.plugin.share.jms.impl.JMSExceptionWrapper: javax.jms.MessageFormatException: Deserialization failed: org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.StorableMessage
Caused by: javax.jms.MessageFormatException: Deserialization failed: org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.StorableMessage
```

Is there any configuration needs to be done or jars to be added?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

org.apache.synapse.message.store.impl.jms.StorableMessage is what you get when you serialize the Synapse Message Context into a JMS store : this is a java object serialized into a binary format

I guess you are using "store" mediator inside your mediation, to serialize your message into a JMS Message Store pointing into Tibco EMS

Why does tibco try to deserialize this message ?

You can send a text/plain message into tibco using send mediator inside your mediation, with an addresse endpoint based on a uri like "jms:/xxxx"

Comment: Yes, I am using the store mediator. I will try using  address endpoint now and will come back.